# Page displaying sections using opacity, following #section and then do Javascript ScrollTo(0,0)

Tags: javascript, css

Here is my app - http://www.shalgreetings.com/ I am trying to override the scroll bar going down to a imagesection in CSS, so that whole app is visible with logo, header and other controls all the times when people navigate through different #sections.  I am not sure where in the CSS, I am making the mistake as clicking on #sections traverses the page. Here is this app's [original inspiration code](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/3182943/Gotta%27%20love%20HTML5_CSS3/index.html#gal1), which has got this right.

Anyone can point me where the problem seems to be in the above app?

Edit - It was not a problem with CSS. Perhaps I am looking for a Javascript solution that would follow the link, but still ScrollTo(0,0).

Answer (score 1):

There is no mistake in your CSS, the inspiration code "cheated" in a way: he used just a few photos so the viewport would never be too short to display everything. In the example you can make your window height short and it will exhibit the same problem.

You probably already know that you can solve this problem with a bit of javascript (onclick="return false;"). I'm afraid there is no pure CSS way from preventing this from happening.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Thanks for clarifying that it cannot be done by CSS alone. But that onclick="return false;" trick wont do, because I need to follow that link **and** then return to top. Perhaps I am looking for javascript solution and unable to find a good one.